# Rails migration is not executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, migration

After creating a *users* table using devise gem, I wanted to add one more attribute in a separate migration file:

```
class AddAutoLoginTokenToUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    add_column :users, :auto_login_token, :string
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :auto_login_token
  end

end
```

Running `rake db:migrate` gives the following confirmation:

```
== 20140421141615 AddAutoLoginTokenToUsersTable: migrating ====================
-- add_column(:users, :auto_login_token, :string)
   -> 0.0020s
== 20140421141615 AddAutoLoginTokenToUsersTable: migrated (0.0021s) ===========
```

But using Rails console or executing on the server gives the following error:

```
undefined method `auto_login_token' for #<User:0x00000103228b80>
```

Do you have any idea why this happened and how to deal with that? Thanks

Comment: This might be an issue of different environments not having the updated migration run on them.  If you were running in a testing environment you'd need to run `rake db:test:prepare` -- is your 'server' the development server?  Is your console also using the development environment?  Whatever the case, are you sure you ran the migration on the appropriate environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the gems you have in use, you may need to restart the console in order for changes to the `User` model to get picked up.

Failing that, check that you ran the migration for the same environment that your console is running. You may have run the migration on the development environment and have the console running on production. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-migrations-in-different-environments) for how to run migrations in different environments:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```